# Send credentials to WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, credentials

I have a webbrowser control that navigates to sharepoint port.

How can i send credentials to webbrowser control, so i can navigate to the site with custom credentials?

Comment: I see you have been here and edited but did you try my solution? Worked well with signing in to a page that does not accept querystring

Comment: i've tried your solution, but it is not working with sharepoint.

Comment: Try my edit below, works well for signing in as a user for a few lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the authentication method used by the server. For form authentication you just need to simulate a form post. But most likely the site is using integrated Windows authentication and you need to [implement IAuthenticate](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx)(Ex) Or impersonate via LogonUser.

Comment: Hi, the site is using integrated windows authentication and i had implemented IAuthenticate in my form  http://izlooite.blogspot.com/2009/06/bypass-integrated-authentication-using.html, but the problem is that this solution woks only if IE is configured to prompt for username and password, in others cases (automatic login...) it doesn't work.