# Using Integrated Windows Authentication credentials with a WebBrowser control in VB6

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, windows-authentication, credentials

I have a VB6 application using a WebBrowser control to access a site. 
I need to push the user's Windows Authentication credentials to the control so he won't get asked to enter his user and password when he accesses a web application in an intranet.

I have seen solutions in .NET like this post.

[Send credentials to WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445963/send-credentials-to-webbrowser)

Is there a way to achieve this with Visual Basic 6?

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 WebBrowser control will exhibit the same behavior as IE--so if the URL is in the trusted sites or intranet zones it should automatically use your network credentials--no coding necessary.

If you want to programmatically add your URL to a zone, use the [SetZoneMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537143.aspx) function.