# WebBrowser.Navigate(); How to pass ntlm credentials

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have created a web page capture utility is run through an httphandler which can access public sites easily and create screenshots.

Problem: I am trying to access a local Sharepoint site, which requires NTLM credentials in order to view the pages I am attempting to make screenshots of.

When I execute WebBrowser.Navigate(Sharepointsite) I get a 401 challenge to pass through the credentials. Now because this is running as a background service I need to pass through the credentials automatically. At the moment, the browser just hangs and waits for the credentials. I have looked at passing the credentials in the headers which can be passed in the Navigate method but still no luck...

This is my code for the executing function.

```
ICredentials cred = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
String authorisationHeader = String.Empty;
private bool Ping(string url)
{
    try
    {
        bool status;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Credentials = cred;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ContentType = "text/html";
        req.Accept = "*/*";
        req.KeepAlive = false;

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            status = (resp.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK");
            WebHeaderCollection c = resp.Headers;
        }
        authorisationHeader = req.Headers.GetValues("Authorization")[0];
        return status;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url, int width, int height)
{
    bool Active = Ping(url);
    if (Active)
    {
        // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
        wb.AllowNavigation = true;
        wb.AllowWebBrowserDrop = true;
        wb.Navigate(url, null, null, authorisationHeader);

        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        //HANGS HERE IF THE SITE NEEDS AUTHENTICATION... Credentials aren't being passed through successfully. HELP!

        while (!isComplete)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
        wb.Dispose();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

If anyone can help me automatically log in to a site requiring authentication that would be amazing! Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send credentials to WebBrowser ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445963/send-credentials-to-webbrowser)

Answer (score 3):

This probably comes back to the IE setting about passing credentials (because the web browser is basically an instance of IE).  So I would add this site to the trusted site on the machine and then check the User Authentication -> Logon -> Automatic Logon with current username and password setting in IE for the trusted sites.

Comment: Thank you.  Sometimes writing code isn't the best solution to a problem -- I've got to remember that.