# Forms Authentication issue with WebBrowser Class in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a site and in this site i m building a functionality to capture a screen  shot of a page. In my site i am using forms authentication.now first of all.

So when user login to the website he/she has to enter the credentials and then go to their profile page.

So now i am just creating a thumbnail of the user profile page using WebBrowser Control but the problem is , i m using forms authentication and it's always capture the login forms page because of forms authentication.

So Please help me ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you will need to perform login programtically for forms authentication. Here is the piece of code which will be required.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, false);
```

And here is more info
http://weblogs.asp.net/joseguay/archive/2009/03/23/the-asp-net-capsule-2-login-programmatically-with-forms-authentication.aspx.

However, be aware that the code you are using for creation of screenshot might not go well with it. So take care of this. These posts might help you in that case [Send credentials to WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445963/send-credentials-to-webbrowser)

Comment: but my question is how to use forms authentication with WebBrowser

Answer (score 0):

You have to simulate forms authentication via WebBrowser control - essentially, use document object model ([Document property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx)) to locate user name/password input boxes, set their values and trigger submit (either inject java-script to do form submit OR use DOM to simulate login button click).

IMO, better way would be to use WebRequest (`HttpWebRequest`) to simulate the POST to login page to do authentication and then issue request to user profile page. Get the page html(from response) and load it in Web Browser control using [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) property.

In case, you have control over the server site, you may modify user profile page to allow un-authenticated access over certain requests (for example, from local machine or specified IP etc).

Comment: see my url will be like this and i am calling MyBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost:3143/Artist/ArtistProfile.aspx?UserId=16"); so when webbrowser call that page internally it goes to the login page because of form authentication .so please tell me how to do that.

Comment: @Anil, once it goes to login page, you have to use DOM to give credentials etc. Alternately, use WebRequest class to do POST request to login page followed by GET request to user profile page - get the html from response and load that into WebBrowser control.